# Trocando elementos nos arrays com uma função. Como fazer?

Tags: javascript

desde já me desculpo pela dúvida de iniciante, mas estou entalada no seguinte problema. O exercicio pede que declaremos uma função chamada "substituir" que tem dois arrays (arrayA, arrayB) e aí remove o último elemento do primeiro (arrayA) e adiciona-o ao segundo (arrayB).

Sendo:

```js
var arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
var arrayB = [4, 5];
```

Agora, usando pop e push, meu código está assim:

```js
var arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
var arrayB = [4, 5];
arrayA.pop ();
arrayB.push (3);
```

A questão é que preciso por *dentro* de uma função ou *com* uma função (realmente não sei como o exercício quer que façamos) e não faço ideia como encaixar isso numa função. Até agora tentei isso, e só dá erro:

```js
var arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
var arrayB = [4, 5];
arrayA.pop ();
arrayB.push (3);


function substituir (){
var resultado = (arrayA,arrayB);
return resultado;
}
```

Alguma ideia de como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sua pergunta está meio vaga, então esta é apenas uma forma de fazer esta substituição usando uma função:

```js
// recebe dois arrays por parametro e troca a última possição
// do primeiro para o segundo
function substituir(array_a, array_b){
  array_b.push(array_a.pop())    
}

var arrayA = [1, 2, 3];
var arrayB = [4, 5];

substituir(arrayA, arrayB)

console.log("Array A", arrayA)
console.log("Array B", arrayB)
```

Comment: Luigi você é um superherói! A pergunta do problema é realmente vaga e me deixou extremamente confusa, mas essa solução funcionou 100 por cento!! Obrigada demais!!

Answer (score 1):

Algumas observações:

O seguinte trecho do seu código `arrayB.push (3);` funciona somente quando o último elemento do arrayA é o número 3. Em qualquer outra situação, o código produz um erro lógico.

Quanto a este trecho `var resultado = (arrayA,arrayB);`, eu não sei qual a sua intenção com ele, ou se você sabe que está utilizando operador vírgula, mas ele apenas atribui o valor do arrayB à variável resultado.

Quanto a solução do problema, você pode tentar algo simples:

```
function substituir(arrA, arrB){
  let x = arrA.pop();
  arrB.push(x);
}
```

Ou um pouco mais enxuto:

```
function substituir(a, b){ b.push(a.pop());}
```

Ou pode testar o tamanho do primeiro array, se você não quiser que o segundo array se encha de `undefined`:

```
function substituir(arrA, arrB){
  if(arrA.length > 0){
    let x = arrA.pop();
    arrB.push(x);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Só usar o `pop` com o `push`:

```
array_b.push(array_a.pop());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sou iniciante também, mas segue aí a minha solução para o problema:

// Usado em ES6 ou superior;

```
const myArrayA = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']; // Array de uma dimensão "String"
const myArrayB = [1, 2, 3, 4]; // Array de uma dimensão "Number"

// Função que retorna um novo Array
const criarNovo = (arg1, arg2) => {
    const [one, ...outros] = arg2; // Usando destructuring para pegar argumentos, ignorando o primeiro.
    for (let i in outros) { //Percorrendo o Array gerado 
        arg1.push(outros[i]); // Adiciona dentro do arg1 que representa o Array o primeiro Array ou segundo, cada item do segundo argumento;
    }
    return arg1; // Retorna um novo Array, caso não retorne nada a função retornara undefined
}

const myArrayC = criarNovo(myArrayA, myArrayB); // Aqui você escolhe quem recebe quem;
console.log(myArrayC); // Log
```