# Mover arrays utilizando "push" e "pop"

Tags: javascript, array

Declarar uma função chamada “mover”, que recebe dois `arrays`, remove o último elemento do primeiro e adiciona-o ao segundo.

Exemplo:

```
var umArray = [1, 2, 3];
var outroArray = [4, 5];

mover(umArray, outroArray);

umArray //deveria ser [1, 2]
outroArray //deveria ser [4, 5, 3]
```

Fiz o seguinte:

```
function mover (umArray,outroArray){
var umArray= [1, 2, 3]
var outroArray=[4, 5]
var pegarElemento = umArray.pop(); 
   outroArray.push( pegarElemento );
}
```

Não sei como prosseguir.

Comment: A mesma pergunta foi feita ontem... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/423599/trocando-elementos-nos-arrays-com-uma-função-como-fazer

Answer (score 1):

Olá é simples a solução veja:

```js
function mover (umArray, outroArray){   
   var pegarElemento = umArray.pop(); 
   outroArray.push(pegarElemento);   
   console.log("primeiro Array", umArray);
   console.log("segundo Array", outroArray);
}
```

```html
<!-- Declarar uma função chamada “mover”, que recebe dois arrays, remove o último elemento do primeiro e adiciona-o ao segundo. -->

<div>
Valor inicial do array 1:
[1, 2, 3]
</div>

<div>
Valor inicial do array 2:
[1, 2]
</div>

<br />
<button onclick="mover([1, 2, 3], [1, 2])" type="button">mover</button>
```

Chamamos a função passando os dois arrays:

```
mover([1, 2, 3], [1, 2]);
```

Depois podemos pegar o ultimo elemento do primeiro array:

```
var pegarElemento = umArray.pop();
```

E ai adicionar ao final do segundo array

```
outroArray.push(pegarElemento);
```

e por fim usamos o console para mostrar o resultado do array:

```
console.log(outroArray);
```